# Are there any jenkins plugins available for developers work easiness (a replacement for web2py)

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, web-deployment, web2py

We are looking for Devops CD process for our python developers work, where currently they are writing and testing codes using web2py.

If we use jenkins, how can we get a better option for the replacement for web2y? Or can we integrate web2py with jenkisn for completing the devops cycle?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming and should be ask on superuser instead